# Nothing Returned for In App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying in app purchases for the first time. My question, why do I get no available product?

I have seen this asked before with either no answers or with answers referencing bad links.

I have a product configured on the iTunes with bundle id.
I have an in app purchase configured for that app.

In my code I do:

```
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productidentifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start] ;
```

I call that with the bundle ID for that in app purchase (i've tried the app ID too).

This delegate function gets called

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

but *products* is an empty array.

This does not get called:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

This does:

```
- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
```

What do I need to check to get the producs?

Comment: Are you running on the simulator? If so its not supported, you will have to use a real device.

Comment: I am on the device. Ran into that hurdle. I add that I am signed out but have not been prompted to enter the test iTunes account password.

Comment: Aha, worth a shot. It took me a while to figure this one out :S - Only other suggestion is to make sure you are using a development provisioning profile for your specific bundleID

Comment: It  took me a long time since the documentation suggests that it does work. The release notes for 5.0.1 say it does not work but there is no mention for 5.1. This whole tangled system of identifiers is just one problem after another.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a real device, and you must also set up a test account in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the IAP product ID instead of app id(or bundle ID). the IAP product ID is created by itune connect. "products is an empty array." means this id(whatever you're use) you requested from itunes store does not exisit.
here's my working code:

```
#define ProductID_IAPUNLOCKALL @"unlockall.myapp"
NSArray *product=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ProductID_IAPUNLOCKALL,nil];
NSSet *nsset = [NSSet setWithArray:product];
SKProductsRequest *request=[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: nsset];
request.delegate=self;
[request start];
```

the "unlockall.myapp" is a uniq string defined in itunes connect.

Comment: I was using what is listed under iTunes as "Product ID:" for the in app purchase.

Comment: @user3344003 did u create the IAP product id? and I was confused by your question did 'didReceiveResponse' get called or not? cause you said 'This delegate function gets called' then 'This does not get called:' but they both refer to same code.

Comment: 1) I have a product ID for the in app purchase. Is that the IAP product ID? (There are so many certificates and ids that I get lost). 2) didReceiveResponse does get called.

Comment: @user3344003 yes that's what I mean. well, if you have the id and the response does get called, then your code should be ok, just wait for few hours for itunes get your IAP ready, sometime it takes time, maybe you can try it tomorrow and it will work. just make sure the id is exactly the same with you get from itunes connect. if you want you can pm me the id string, i can do a test on my app.

Comment: It's been set up several days. I wonder if it is being routed to the store rather than the sandbox. Is there some connect between the IAP and the app? Do I have to be in a specific app to download its purchases? (I am in the defined app. Could something need to be set there?)

Comment: @user3344003 no, when it comes to the IAP there's no difference between store or sandbox, only test account will working in sandbox, the IAP should be same. as you metioned the defined app-- did you set the app bundle ID correctly?